# Retrieving specified rows in Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

**The question**

*Is there a way to programmatically retrieve only the rows witch match some specific criteria - for example rows having specific indexes?*

The API has a method - [`rows()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows()), which results can be manipulated a little by providing a [`selector-modifier`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) argument. However, using it I am able to use the current table search at most, not a custom one.

**The problem**

For better understanding, I'll provide more details about what I am trying to achieve.

I am using the [Select extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/). I would like to select some rows at once using an external trigger. Now I do it like this:

```
myTable.rows().every(function () {
    // ...
    // Check if the row should be selected and if so:
    this.select();
    // ...
});
```

However, this causes firing of the same number of `select` events on the table as the number of selected rows. I have a handler bound to this event, which performs a request to an external API, based on the selected rows. Since I cannot discern which `select` was the last one, my handler ends up spamming the external API needlessly because of the number of events.

**Solutions**

1. Retrieve only matching rows and use [`rows().select()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().select()) on them.

I think that would be the best solution, because the `select` event would be fired only once. However, I have no idea how to do it - hence this question.

2. Prevent the handler from calling the external API until the selecting process is finished.

I thought up two hacky solutions which I'll use as a last resort:

- Not use an avent handler at all and simply call the API after the [`rows().every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) loop - I still have to use the handler to deal with manual row selection, but that'll probably do.
- Iterate through the rows twice - first time to check which row would be the last to be selected, then disable the handler, do a second loop which actually selects the rows, and enable the handler before selecting the last row

I hope the whole question isn't too confusing. To be clear - the thing I would like to find an answer for is the question on the top, in italics.

Comment: Well written question by the way. Really nice to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector-modifier is only for when you're selecting all rows. It's not for limiting the rows by a selector. For that you would use the row-selector, which is much more flexible:

https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

There are several examples on that page so I won't go through the options here.

As you suggest is the case, if you use this selector and then call .select() on the returned rowset, the callback will only fire once.